# Stubbing a get method using Sinon

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

I'm trying to stub the get method of an object with properties,

Works fine:

```
sinon.stub(input.model, 'get');
input.model.get.returns(10);
```

but consider if we need to stub some specific property in the object,

eg:

```
input.model.get('yourValue')
```

↪ how this can be stubbed? Any idea?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

stub.withArgs() should do what you want. See http://sinonjs.org/docs/#stubs.

```
sinon.stub(input.model, 'get').withArgs('yourValue').returns(10);
```

Sinon has since [changed](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.4.1/stubs/) this syntax:

```
class Foo {
  get bar() { 
    return 'yolo'; 
  }
}

const myObj = new Foo();

sinon.stub(myObj, 'bar').get(() => 'swaggins');

myObj.bar; // 'swaggins'
```

Comment: Now, you could also do `sinon.stub(myObj, 'bar').value('swaggins')`.

Comment: 2022 update. I came here looking for a way to stub a getter for cypress (which uses sinon under the hood). Accepted answer didn't work for me. @PaulRazvanBerg did. Life saver :D